# Fully functional SyncML compliant WBXML encoder-decoder?

Tags: syncml, wbxml

Is there any WBXML encoder-decoder available which is atleast fully compliant for SyncML 1.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a converter that works as expected. Works for all versions of SyncML.

**http://libwbxml.aymerick.com/browser/wbxmlTestSuite/trunk/TestSuite.bat?rev=6**

Comment: This link is dead now. Could you please share another link ?